# How to remove a specific line from a large file with python?

Tags: python, xml, file

For work I have to process an XML-based file: place it in another directory, change extension (from .xaf to .xml), read some info from lines and remove two specific lines from the file (after it has been replaced. 
I got everything working except for the last part. I need to remove two specific lines (or two specific parts from a line if the content of the xml is written in one line). That should not be a problem, there are already many posts about it on stackoverflow. The solution often given is to read it from the source file and copy it line by line (except for the line that needs to be deleted) for the whole file. 
The problem is that the files i need to process are very big (anywhere from 100.000 to >5.000.000 lines), and there are a lot of files to process so doing this method takes a long time.
Is there a way to copy the file and edit the content directly, instead of copying the file line by line? The parts that need to be deleted are always somewhere in the top 20 lines.

What I tried was copying the files from the source to the destination, and then opening the source file again to read the first 20 lines and copying those to the destination file. However, this meant the whole destination file was overwritten (so anything after those 20 lines was gone).

Does anyone has an idea on how to handle this? Many thanks

example part:\

```
   \<companyIdent>XXXXX\</companyIdent>\
\<companyName>Company1\</companyName>\
\<taxRegistrationCountry>NL\</taxRegistrationCountry>\
\<taxRegIdent>123456789\</taxRegIdent>\
\<streetAddress>
    \<streetname>Address1\</streetname>\
    \<city>CITY\</city>\
    \<postalCode>1234AB\</postalCode>\
    \<country>NL\</country>\</streetAddress>\
\<customersSuppliers>
   \<customerSupplier>
      \<custSupID>C0001\</custSupID>\
```

I want to remove<streetAddress> and </streetAddress>. Only these two tags, so not the content in it (that's why i was thinking of removing lines instead of parsing it)

Comment: There are many posts on [reading large files](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+read+large+file+edit+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: show us a minimal reproduction case of one file with 2 or 3 lines. With actual output and desired output.

Comment: @mplungjan and none of them relate to this problem. Martijn: use lxml library. Do not count on XML files having specific content in specific places. It will bite you in the future.

Comment: @BłażejMichalik these '.xaf' files are official audit documents, which follow a government-regulated structure. There are xsd files available online.

I will check out the library you mentioned!

Comment: One approach is to update a file in place is to use mmap which allows treating a file as a mutable string.  A tutorial on this method [Python mmap: Improved File I/O With Memory Mapping](https://realpython.com/python-mmap/) shows it provides over an order of magnitude speed performance for some functions (i.e. your mileage may vary).

Comment: Could you add a small example of source XML and which lines are to be removed?

Comment: @AlexandraDudkina I did now!

Comment: I suspect that the problem is that you're using the wrong algorithm rather than that the files are too large. You need to read the whole file anyway, and if linear time is still too slow then the only way is to switch to another language. -- ((tl;dr. show us your working code))

Comment: If the bottleneck is XML parsing, you can only skip it if the XML is "nice enough" (no comment/string escape/etc.) (that you can use string search/regex)

Answer (score 1):

Using event-based SAX parser you can filter tags with low memory usage and good performance:

```
from xml.sax import make_parser
from xml.sax.saxutils import XMLFilterBase, XMLGenerator

# filter class which skips startElement and endElement events
# for tags configured
class MyFilter(XMLFilterBase):

    def __init__(self, tags_to_exclude, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        # tags to exclude
        self._tags_to_exclude = tags_to_exclude

    def startElement(self, name, attrs):
        if name not in self._tags_to_exclude:
            super().startElement(name, attrs)

    def endElement(self, name):
        if name not in self._tags_to_exclude:
            super().endElement(name)


# define tags to be ecluded    
tags_to_exclude = {'streetAddress'}

# create filter    
reader = MyFilter(tags_to_exclude, make_parser())

# parse source and write to target
with open('target.xml', 'w') as file:
    handler = XMLGenerator(file)
    reader.setContentHandler(handler)
    reader.parse('source.xml')
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me solve this! This however filters the whole contents of the stuff between the tags, but I want only the actual text <streetaddress> and <\streetaddress> removed. I figured that out thanks to @user202729 .
your code is still useful for future things i might need to do with the file, so thanks for the help!